# Need to call a Javascript method from the code-behind

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net, web-services

I have my code-behind class and there I have an `EventListener`, I need to refresh the whole page when my `EventListener` catches an ´Event´.

How do I do this? I have a JavaScript function in my client-side `window.location.reload(true)`.

The problem is that the javascript never gets executed.

Code-Behind:

```
private void WebResponse_Msg(object sender, EventArgs e){
     ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(Page), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "refresh();", true);
 }
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function refresh() {
        window.location.reload(true);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server side code can not trigger javascript (client side code) whenever you want (like when an event is triggered).

However there are several workarounds that I mention 2 of them:

1.Using [SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr)

2.Logging that event when triggered in a Session, and checking the session value by ajax periodically.